# ISPreventDowngrade is quitting without a prompt

Tags: setup-project, downgrade, installshield-2013

I inherited a project off of a prior developer with the company. We're running into a minor issue in the field where users attempting to install an older version of the software aren't getting any sort of a prompt; the setup just closes immediately. I'm trying to get up to speed on InstallShield, but I also don't want to beat my head against a brick wall any more than I have to. The ISPreventDowngrade settings are as follows:

```
Sequence Number: 450
Conditions: ISFOUNDNEWERPRODUCTVERSION
Comments:
```

Is there a way to change this so that it prompts the user to ask whether they want to downgrade, or at least display a helpful messages saying that they will have to uninstall the current version to install the older one?

If it helps, this is where it seems to fail in the log (codes redacted because I never know what might be sensitive):

```
7-6-2017[10:20:58 AM]: Upgrade check: checking product code {X555XX55-555X-55X5-55X5-55X5X55555X5}
7-6-2017[10:20:58 AM]: Upgrade check: obtained package code {XX5X5X55-5X55-5XX5-55XX-55555X55555X} from machine, current package code is {55XX55XX-5XX5-55X5-X55X-XX55X5XX5X5X}
7-6-2017[10:20:58 AM]: Upgrade check: later product version already installed
7-6-2017[10:21:00 AM]: Dumping setup.ini...
```

Comment: Are they installing it silently? Otherwise the built-in downgrade prevention should have shown a message, unless it was edited. Note that it will be difficult to modify the old installer unless you plan to reissue it, and it's generally best to keep moving forwards.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: They are not installing it with the silent option. And yes, we plan on replacing the installer on our site. We figure that most people will be redownloading it when they want it.

Comment: Hmm. If you have a chance, try a simple test project: new basic MSI, add some exe, build; upgrade version and product code, build another; install the second, and then try to install the first. If that has the desired behavior, try to figure out what differs between that and your real project, in items related to ISFOUNDNEWERPRODUCTVERSION and ISPreventDowngrade.